# ElasticSearch terms query match against all values in multi-value field

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch (5.4) I have documents of the following structure:

```
{
    "email": {
        type: "text",
        "fields": {
           "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
           }
        }
    }
}
```

where `email` is a multi-valued field (any document can have multiple emails associated with it) representing an email address. I also have a list of "allowed email addresses."

I would like to write a query to find documents that include any email addresses outside of the white list.

For instance, if we had:

```
whitelist = ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com']

document1: {email: ['email1@test.com', 'email4@test.com']}
document2: {email: ['email1@test.com']}
document3: {email: ['email5@test.com', 'email6@test.com']}
```

We would want the query to find documents 1 and 3.

My first instinct was to use a query of the form:

```
{
    bool: {
        must_not: {terms: {email.keyword: [whitelist]}}}
    }
}
```

However, this only returns document3 --- a document where NONE of the emails match the whitelist.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this? Unfortunately, there is too much data to use a script query.